# c# - How to disorder a List<MyObject>

Tags: c#, list, random

I would like to random sort a `List<MyObject>`.
Is it possible ?

---

I though about another solution, using specific random number:
I mean, if I could do something like that : **random.next(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)**

If this call return 3, I could set the next call **random.next(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)** without the 3 which could return me anything excepted 3, etc...

Then I could finish to disordered my own List.

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: Nice, I didn't find it on stack ! great post, I'll take a look <3

Comment: Note the technical term for this is "shuffling".